# Spring 3 - Combination of @PathVariable and HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, annotations

I have this controller mapping

```
@RequestMapping("/{language}/payment/{id}/reward/{rewardId}/name/{name}/address/{address}")
public String paymentPackage(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable Long
rewardId, @PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String address,
ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request)
```

It works well, but now I need to pass "HttpServletRequest request" to other methods, but request does not contain variables from REST URL (id, name, ...)
Is it possible to have this variables in HttpServletRequest too? 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the other method(/controller)'s signature?

Comment: The other method is not in the controller, it is a service which is using the request object. I think signature of this method is irelevant to the question. It is simple as doXXX(HttpServletRequest request)

Comment: Why dont you store those `@PathVariable` variables in a simple bean and then pass the bean along with `request` to the down stream methods? IDE refactor function is your friend here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a filter and modify request to contain all needed variables. Or modify the request inside the controler.

```
 request.setAttribute("name", name);
```

Answer (score 0):

set the value in model and access from the page. In case if you need to access from other method pass it to method as parameter.

```
model.addAttribute("request", request);
```

Comment: I have request object, but its parameters are null, since i use @PathVariable and rest url. What i want is to have them in both path variables and request.

Comment: you can't have like that.Path variable should be bound to a URI template variable. And can't be accessed by request. In case u want to access by request pass it as a parameter. This can be accessed through      request